# Get files separately from different multiple file inputs

Tags: c#, .net, razor, file-upload, file-io

Lets say I have a html form

```
<form id="frm" method="post" action="upload.cshtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input multiple type="file" name="file1" />
    <input multiple type="file" name="file2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The from has two inputs each accepting multiple files. When this form is submitted, `Request.Files["file1"]` will only give the first file in the file1 input. In order to access the rest of the files I would have to iterate Request.Files[] in a loop. The latter method however gives all files of both inputs. How do I get the files separately so that I can perform different actions on the different sets of files?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to define appropriate parameters to the action method:

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file1, 
    IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file2)
{
    // process file1 and file2
}
```

The `file1` enumerable will contain all files from the input with the name `file1` and so does `file2` contain the files from `file2`.

Comment: true. this is just what i already mentioned. But how do I differentiate between which files are of file1 and which files are of file2?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how this will be used in the cshtml file?

Comment: I copied your `<form.../>` from the question 1:1 only changing the action to point to my `Upload` action. BTW: You should use the `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... }` helper instead of the "manually typed form".